# Spring Integration Mono<?> or CompletableFuture<?> with async false

Tags: spring-integration

How can we achieve the equivalent of `ListenableFuture` async=false with `Mono<?>` or `CompletableFuture` in **Spring Integration 5.x**?

We have a lot of reactive handlers (service activator pattern) from a common library and do not wish to rewrite them as blocking for normal `GenericHandler`.

Kindly suggest.

**P.S:** As per documentation ListenableFuture is deprecated in Spring Integration 6.x, hence want to implement the future (Spring Integration 6.x) way. Thanks

**Sample:**

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow monoAsyncFalseFlow() {
        
        // @formatter:off
        return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(() -> "Good Morning")
                            .handle(monoResponseHandler(), ec -> ec.async(false))
                            // expect "Good Morning", however it is still a Mono<"Good Morning"> though async=false
                            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, m -> m.getPayload())
                            .get();
        // @formatter:on
    }
    
    @Bean
    public GenericHandler<String> monoResponseHandler() {
        
        return (p, h) -> Mono.just(p);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `async=false`, the `Mono` or `CompletableFuture` is going to be as a payload of a reply message from your handler. And from here you are on your own to deal with that payload in the next step of your integration flow.

Probably, if you share some example of your scenario, we can help to determine what and how has to be done in your configuration or logic.

Comment: As I said: to evaluate that `Mono` reply, you have to use `async=true`, or `subscribe()` to it manually where you receive this message afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, `subscribe()` will not wait for completion, hence how do I perform `async=true` on the `Mono` so that the `log()` waits and prints the result of the `Mono`. Also, the `ec -> ec.async(false)` has no effect?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. You just do `ec.async(true)` on that `handle()` and `Mono` is going to be evaluated before its value is sent to the next channel. In your case that is a channel with `log()` interceptor. Why doesn't that approach make sense for you?

Comment: Apologies. My bad, was trying with `async=false`. It is working perfectly fine (evaluating the result of the Mono) with `async=true`. Thx a lot !! Just for my understanding, when it is `async=true` does it become a blocking call?

Comment: No, it does not. See `AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput()` logic.